# Can't get the value of form in .jsp?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, tomcat

I can't get the value of the form - I still get 'null'. What am I doing wrong??

```
<br><br>
<form  method = "POST">
        <label>From:</label>
        <input type="date" name="inputFrom"
           value="2020-01-01"
           min="2000-01-01" max="2022-12-31">
</form>


<% out.println(request.getParameter("inputFrom")); %>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate it better? Are you submitting this page to itself? Do you have a button that is submitting the form or are you making it using Javascript?

Comment: Yes, sure. I'm trying to submit this page to itself. Do I need a button to do this?

Comment: How do you submit it?

Comment: Well, to be honest I thought adding method="post" would be enough... Could you please explain how should I do it? I'm really new to this...

Comment: The method POST only specifies what HTTP should be used to submit the form. It does not fire a submission.
You may use a **submit** button to do it. Here is an example
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

Comment: Great! It really work preety well! Thank you Alex de Moraes!
Add this comment as an answer and I will mark it as best! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method POST only specifies what HTTP should be used to submit the form. It does not fire a submission. You may use a submit button to do it. [Here](http://w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp) you can see an example of how to build a minimum form and provides a submit button.
In your code:

```
<br><br>
<form  method = "POST">
        <label>From:</label>
        <input type="date" name="inputFrom"
           value="2020-01-01"
           min="2000-01-01" max="2022-12-31">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<% out.println(request.getParameter("inputFrom")); %>
```